# Can someone help me refactor this C# linq business logic for efficiency?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I feel like this is not a very efficient way of using linq. I was hoping somebody on here would have a suggestion for a refactor. I realize this code is not very pretty, as I was in a complete rush.

```
public class Workflow
{

    public void AssignForms()
    {

        using (var cntx = new ProjectBusiness.Providers.ProjectDataContext())
        {
            var emplist = (from e in cntx.vw_EmployeeTaskLists where e.OwnerEmployeeID == null select e).ToList();
            foreach (var emp in emplist)
            {
                // if employee has a form assigned: break;

                if (emp.GRADE > 15 || (emp.Pay_Plan.ToLower().Contains("al") || emp.Pay_Plan.ToLower().Contains("ex")))
                {
                    //Assign278();
                }
                else if ((emp.Series.Contains("0905") || emp.Series.Contains("0511") || emp.Series.Contains("0110") || emp.Series.Contains("1801")) || (emp.GRADE >= 12 && emp.GRADE <= 15))
                {
                    var emptask = new ProjectBusiness.Providers.EmployeeTask();
                    emptask.TimespanID = cntx.Timespans.SingleOrDefault(t => t.BeginDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year & t.EndDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).TimespanID;
                    var FormID = (from f in cntx.Forms where f.FormName.Contains("450") select f.FormID).FirstOrDefault();
                    var TaskStatusID = (from s in cntx.TaskStatus where s.StatusDescription.ToLower() == "not started" select s.TaskStatusID).FirstOrDefault();
                    Assign450((int)emp.EmployeeID, FormID, TaskStatusID, emptask);
                    cntx.EmployeeTasks.InsertOnSubmit(emptask);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Assign185();
                }

            }
            cntx.SubmitChanges();
        }

    }

    private void Assign450(int EmployeeID, int FormID, int TaskStatusID, ProjectBusiness.Providers.EmployeeTask emptask)
    {
        emptask.FormID = FormID;
        emptask.OwnerEmployeeID = EmployeeID;
        emptask.AssignedToEmployeeID = EmployeeID;
        emptask.TaskStatusID = TaskStatusID;
        emptask.DueDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Comment: first thing I would do is refactor the logic in the if statements into either boolean variables that say what they do or better still methods.

Comment: Just leave `emplist` as an `IEnumerable` (no `.ToList()` ) and you should see improvements immediately.

Comment: That code is rife with magic numbers, at the very least those should be constants...

Comment: You may need to double check the logic.  There are a few subtle bugs in here. `t.BeginDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year & t.EndDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year` should probably be `&&`

Comment: You also are requiring for the timespanid and formid on each pass of the loop.  These should be pretty constant by the queries you have in the code so it would be much faster to calculate them on the outside.

Comment: Could all of your `.Contains()` calls be replaced by `==` statements?

Comment: @Matthew Whited: Yes they can be set to ==, I have now done so. I threw this together in a big rush, so I hadn't checked everything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a LINQ provider try to use queries and not loops.

```
public void AssignForms()
{

    using (var cntx = new ProjectDataContext())
    {
        var emplist = from e in cntx.vw_EmployeeTaskLists
                      where e.OwnerEmployeeID == null
                      select e;

        var timeSpanId = cntx.Timespans.SingleOrDefault(t =>
                            t.BeginDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year &&
                            t.EndDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year
                            ).TimespanID;

        var formID = (from f in cntx.Forms
                      where f.FormName.Contains("450")
                      select f.FormID).FirstOrDefault();

        var taskStatusID = (from s in cntx.TaskStatus
                            let status = s.StatusDescription.ToLower()
                            where status == "not started"
                            select s.TaskStatusID).FirstOrDefault();

        var assign278 = from emp in emplist
                        let payPlanInv = emp.Pay_Plan.ToUpperInvariant()
                        where emp.GRADE > 15 || (
                              payPlanInv.Contains("AL") ||
                              payPlanInv.Contains("EX")
                              )
                        select emp;

        var assign450 = from emp in emplist
                        where (emp.Series.Contains("0905") ||
                               emp.Series.Contains("0511") ||
                               emp.Series.Contains("0110") ||
                               emp.Series.Contains("1801")
                              ) || (
                               emp.GRADE >= 12 &&
                               emp.GRADE <= 15)
                        select emp;

        var assign185 = from emp in emplist
                        where !assign278.Select(e => e.EmployeeID)
                                        .Contains(emp.EmployeeID)
                              && !assign450.Select(e => e.EmployeeID)
                                           .Contains(emp.EmployeeID)
                        select emp;

        // do inserts here
        cntx.EmployeeTasks.InsertAllOnSubmit(assign450.Select(emp =>
                     new EmployeeTask()
                     {
                         TimespanID = timeSpanId,
                         FormID = formID,
                         OwnerEmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,
                         AssignedToEmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,
                         TaskStatusID = taskStatusID,
                         DueDate = DateTime.Today
                     }));
        cntx.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a fast best guess... it may require some work to get the way you want.

Comment: This makes sense. It's much more efficient. It worked almost perfectly... only had to tweak a little.

Comment: Excellent... glad I could help.  Changing those `.Contains(...)` to `==` will help the query plan for the server (should change from `LIKE` to `=`.)   If you are using LINQ2SQL and would like to see the query that is send to the server call the `.ToString()` method on the query.  This may help you better understand what LINQ is doing for you.